# T-SQL - Get a list of all As which have the same set of Bs

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm struggling with a tricky SQL query that I'm trying to write. Have a look at the following table:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

Now, from this table, I essentially want a list of all As which have the exact same set of Bs and give each set an incrementing ID.

Hence, the output set for the above would be:

```
+---+----+
| A | ID |
+---+----+
| 1 |  1 |
| 3 |  1 |
| 2 |  2 |
| 4 |  2 |
+---+----+
```

Thanks.

Edit: If it helps, I have a list of all distinct values of B that are possible in another table.

Edit: Thank you so much for all the innovative answers. Was able to learn a lot indeed.

Comment: If you had 3 more rows: `4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4` ?

Comment: I have thought about taking a distinct list of As, then storing the CSV list of Bs for every A within a temp table. Finally I would find the entries in the table which have the same CSV strings.

Comment: There is a commn trick to build CSV string using xml function, don't need a temp table: http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Nevertheless, your question about the additional rows is thought provoking. I may have to change the desired output a bit.

Comment: @edc65: Rephrased the question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is mathematical trick to solve your tricky select:

```
with pow as(select *, b * power(10, row_number() 
              over(partition by a order by b)) as rn from t)
select a, dense_rank() over( order by sum(rn)) as rn 
from pow
group by a
order by rn, a
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b98d/11

This of course will work only for limited distinct count as you will get overflow. Here is more general solution with strings:

```
select a, 
dense_rank() over(order by (select  '.' + cast(b as varchar(max))
                            from t t2 where t1.a = t2.a
                            order by b
                            for xml path(''))) rn
from t t1
group by a
order by rn, a
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b98d/29

Comment: Although I upvoted, you should change two things.  First, you really need a separator for the `b` values in the string solution (how many elements are in "123").  Second, you should never use `varchar()` without a length parameter in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context; being explicit prevents further errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are absolutely right. 123 and 12 and 3 would give same rank. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```sql
select a, dense_rank() over (order by g) as id_b
from (
  select a,
  (select b from MyTable s where s.a=a.a order by b FOR XML PATH('')) g
  from MyTable a
  group by a
) a
order by id_b,a
```

Or maybe using a CTE (I avoid them when possible)

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31c14/6)

As a side note, this is the output of the inner query using the sample data in the question:

```
a   g
1   <b>2</b><b>3</b>
2   <b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b>
3   <b>2</b><b>3</b>
4   <b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b>
```

Comment: Row number will not give you the right result set, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You were right, sorry. I think it can be done with row_number, but dense_rank is better fit.

Comment: See my comment @Giorgi's equivalent solution.

Comment: @Gordon There **is** a separator in my solution. It is the default xlm open/close tag. If it is the right separator, it depends upon the range and type of b values.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
I am changing the code, but it will get bigger now, took help from
[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) for concatinating strings

```
Select [A],
   Left(M.[C],Len(M.[C])-1) As [D] into #tempSomeTable
From
(
    Select distinct T2.[A], 
        (
            Select Cast(T1.[B] as VARCHAR) + ',' AS [text()]
            From sometable T1
            Where T1.[A] = T2.[A]
            ORDER BY T1.[A]
            For XML PATH ('')
        ) [C]
    From sometable T2
 )M

  SELECT t.A, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.[D]) [ID] FROM
  #tempSomeTable t
   inner join
  (SELECT [D] FROM(
  SELECT [D], COUNT([A]) [D_A] from 
   #tempSomeTable t
  GROUP BY [D] )P where [C_A]>1)t1 on t1.[D]=t.[D]
```

Comment: Sum? try with `2,4,6` and `1,3,8`

Comment: Thanks, changed it to string comparison.

Comment: Added the concatinating string logic, now it should be giving the required output

Comment: Step by step you are arriving to my answer :) . No need of a temp table.

Comment: ... and mine is approaching yours too.

Comment: Your solution looks much simpler. But you still need to consider the case where there are other mismatching patterns, such as (5,2),(5,4) in the above example. That needs to be excluded.

Comment: Tried adding rows (5,2) and (5,4), there is a new id_b == 3, no problem. Can you explain what worries you?

Comment: I guess, what I wanted to say is that in the cases of (5,2) and (5,4) should there be an output with id_b==3? Because then we would get an A which doesn't have a set in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a long winded approach, by finding sets with the same elements (using `EXCEPT` bidirectionally to eliminate, and just done a half diagonal cartesian product), then pairing equal sets up, stamping each pair with a `ROW_NUMBER()`, before unpivoting the pairs of `A's` into to your final output where the equivalent sets are projected as rows which have the same `id`.

```
WITH joinedSets AS
(
    SELECT t1.A as t1A, t2.A AS t2A
    FROM MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t1.B = t2.B
        AND t1.A < t2.A
),
equalSets AS
(
    SELECT js.t1A, js.t2A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY js.t1A) AS Id
    FROM joinedSets js
    GROUP BY js.t1A, js.t2A
    HAVING NOT EXISTS ((SELECT mt.B FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.A = js.t1A)
           EXCEPT (SELECT mt.B FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.A = js.t2A))
         AND NOT EXISTS ((SELECT mt.B FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.A = js.t2A) 
           EXCEPT (SELECT mt.B FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.A = js.t1A))
)
SELECT A, Id
FROM equalSets
UNPIVOT
(
    A
    FOR ACol in (t1A, t2A)
) unp;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/501aa/31)

As it stands, this solution will only work with pairs of sets, not triples etc. A general `NTuple` type solution is probably possible (but beyond my brain right now).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple, fast, but approximate solution.
It is possible that `CHECKSUM_AGG` returns the same checksum for different sets of B.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (A int, B int);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4),(3, 2),(3, 3),(4, 2),(4, 3),(4, 4);

SELECT
    A
    ,CHECKSUM_AGG(B) AS CheckSumB
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHECKSUM_AGG(B) ORDER BY A) AS GroupNumber
FROM @T
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A, GroupNumber;
```

**Result set**

```
A    CheckSumB    GroupNumber
-----------------------------
1    1            1
2    5            1
3    1            2
4    5            2
```

For exact solution group by `A` and concatenate all `B` values into a long (binary) string using either FOR XML, CLR, or T-SQL function. Then you can partition `ROW_NUMBER` by that concatenated string to assign numbers to the groups. As shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exact, rather than approximate, solution.  It uses nothing more advanced than INNER JOIN and GROUP BY (and, of course, the DENSE_RANK() to get the ID you want).

It is also general, in that it allows for B values to be repeated within an A group.

```
SELECT   A,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN_EQUIVALENT_A) AS ID

FROM     (
          SELECT   MATCHES.A1 AS A,
                   MIN(MATCHES.A2) AS MIN_EQUIVALENT_A

          FROM     (
                    SELECT   T1.A AS A1,
                             T2.A AS A2,
                             COUNT(*) AS NUM_B_VALS_MATCHED

                    FROM     (
                              SELECT   A,
                                       B,
                                       COUNT(*) AS B_VAL_FREQ
                              FROM     MyTable
                              GROUP BY A,
                                       B
                             ) AS T1

                             INNER JOIN

                             (
                              SELECT   A,
                                       B,
                                       COUNT(*) AS B_VAL_FREQ
                              FROM     MyTable
                              GROUP BY A,
                                       B
                             ) AS T2

                             ON T1.B = T2.B
                                AND T1.B_VAL_FREQ = T2.B_VAL_FREQ

                    GROUP BY T1.A,
                             T2.A
                   ) AS MATCHES

                   INNER JOIN

                   (
                    SELECT   A,
                             COUNT(DISTINCT B) AS NUM_B_VALS_TOTAL
                    FROM     MyTable
                    GROUP BY A
                   ) AS CHECK_TOTALS_A1

                   ON MATCHES.A1 = CHECK_TOTALS_A1.A
                      AND MATCHES.NUM_B_VALS_MATCHED
                          = CHECK_TOTALS_A1.NUM_B_VALS_TOTAL

                   INNER JOIN

                   (
                    SELECT   A,
                             COUNT(DISTINCT B) AS NUM_B_VALS_TOTAL
                    FROM     MyTable
                    GROUP BY A
                   ) AS CHECK_TOTALS_A2

                   ON MATCHES.A2 = CHECK_TOTALS_A2.A
                      AND MATCHES.NUM_B_VALS_MATCHED
                          = CHECK_TOTALS_A2.NUM_B_VALS_TOTAL

          GROUP BY MATCHES.A1
         ) AS EQUIVALENCE_TABLE

ORDER BY 2,1
;
```